# Doubt regarding scattering and bound states in quantum mechanics

Tags: quantum-mechanics, potential, scattering

I just started studying quantum mechanics from Introduction to Quantum Mechanics by D. J. Griffiths. At the beginning of the second chapter, he proves that we cannot have negative energies in the time-independent Schrödinger equation. Later though, while analysing the Dirac Delta potential case, he explicitly chooses the energy of the system to be negative, that too for bound states, which in general give normalisable solutions to the time independent Schrödinger equation, unlike scattering states, which may not. Can anyone please resolve this ambiguity that I am encountering?

Comment: I addressed a similar question [here](http://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/253589/can-we-have-e-0-in-schr%C3%B6dingers-equation/253591#253591). Basically, the lower bound for the energy is the minimum of the potential $V(x)$. For a free particle ($V(x) = 0$) this reduces to saying the energy must be positive.

Comment: That's for a free particle. What about a bound particle? And even though the solution of the time independent Schrödinger equation may turn out to be non normalisable, the overall solution of the time dependent one can be made normalisable.

Comment: The lower bound is the minimum of the potential $V(x)$. In the Dirac delta case this is $-\infty$ so there's no constraint.

Comment: The minimum of the potential in Dirac delta case is 0

Comment: It's not.$\hspace{0mm}$

Comment: How is it possible? I don't get it. The Dirac delta has the value zero everywhere and infinity at zero, isn't it?

Comment: Maybe this video about the sifting property of the Dirac delta distribution (under an integral , NOT by itself) might help: https://youtu.be/bfOVOnSU34M. I am not sure it applies in your case, but the Dirac distribution is very often combined with an integral.